# Use array for keys in Ruby, then add two options per key

Tags: arrays, ruby

**edit** Duh, hashes require unique keys (unless you're doing something weird, as in the comments). Keeping this up in case someone else makes the same mistake.

I've got an array of column names, and would like to end up with a hash where those column names form keys, each appearing twice in the hash with different values each time. An example is probably easier to understand:

```
cols = ["test", "data"] # input
{"test" => "asc", "test" => "desc", "data" => "asc", "data" => "desc"} #expected output
```

I tried to use `map`, but as I've set it up it's nesting too much:

```
cols.map { |c| [c, ["asc", "desc"]] }.to_h
> {"test" => ["asc", "desc"], "data" => ["asc", "desc"]}

cols.map { |c| [[c, "asc"], [c, "desc"]] }.to_h
> {["test", "asc"]=>["test", "desc"], ["data", "asc"]=>["data", "desc"]}
```

Comment: You can't create a hash that has different values for the same key.

Comment: @Casper Yes , if you really want to - [you can](https://ideone.com/Dgch3j) (sort of).

Comment: @steenslag : Perhaps you could add your suggestion as a possible alternative. I admit that the user really needs to know what he is doing here, so some I would recommend adding some warning advice, but there can be useful applications. I wonder if it would not be clearer (from the viewpoint of overall readability) to then explicitly use the `object_id` as Hash key, instead of doing it in the background with `compare_by_identity`....

Comment: @Casper Oh wow, I feel like an idiot - somehow I missed that, even though it's totally obvious in retrospect. Thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want, contradicts the definition of a Hash, where keys need to be unique.

If one key is supposed to have several values, I suggest that you model those values as either arrays (as in your first solution), or as Set.

Hence if you resulting Hash is called `h`, you could make a structure so that

```
h['test']
```

is a `Set` having the elements "asc"  and "desc":

```
require 'set'
...
h = cols.map { |c| [c, Set.new(["asc", "desc"])] }.to_h
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was an array of arrays.

```
cols.map { |c| [c, "asc"] }.append(*cols.map { |c| [c, "desc"] })
> [["test", "asc"], ["data", "asc"], ["test", "desc"], ["data", "desc"]]
```

This has the benefit of not breaking the laws of Ruby.